# Google Maps iOS Draw circle using pan or touch gesture & show marker inside drawn circle

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

[image: Show cluster of marker inside google maps iOS]How to show some markers inside the circle I have drawn on screen with touch(pan) gesture.